# Angular Hash based routing ignoring route path

Tags: angular

I am making an extension and want to open up the popup to a specific route. but when I open the popup with URL

```
moz-extension://adf...as/dist/extension/index.html#/home/otherpage
```

it is ignoring the `#/home/otherpage` hash route and directing to

```
moz-extension://adf...as/dist/extension/index.html#/home/root
```

In the `index.html` I have the base href set to

```
<base href="/dist/extension/index.html">
```

I can't just use the base href of `/dist/extension/` because it doesn't know to load the `index.html` file and I cant use `/dist/extension/index.html/` with the ending `/` cause then angular looks for modules under `moz-extension://adf6cbb0...as/dist/extension/index.html/` directory which isn't correct.

Output from route traces

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
    NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/home/connect')
        Object { id: 1, url: "/home/connect", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null }

Router Event: RouteConfigLoadStart
    RouteConfigLoadStart(path: home)
        Object { route:  Object { path: "home", loadChildren: loadChildren(), canActivate: (1) […], … } }

Router Event: NavigationCancel
    NavigationCancel(id: 1, url: '/home/connect')
        Object { id: 1, url: "/home/connect", reason: "Navigation ID 1 is not equal to the current navigation id 2" }

Router Event: NavigationStart
    NavigationStart(id: 2, url: '/home')
        Object { id: 2, url: "/home", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had a service that was loading data and routing to `/home` ‍♂️.